# Wildcard to match JUNOS

Tags: juniper-junos

Hi I am trying to match routing instances with names other then VPLS-*
basically any name that starts with V* but is not VPLS-*

I tried multiple different iterations of below but it seems to ignore all name that start with V*

```
set groups ALLOW_MARTIAN_192 routing-instances <"![VPLS-*], V*"> routing-options martians 192.0.0.0/24 orlonger allow
```

any help?

Comment: basically, I want to match all names that first character is V and anything afterwards but is not VPLS-*

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible within the confines of the Junos apply-group regex:

In order to use the `!` operator to negate a match, you have to specify a *character class* in square brackets `[]`, however putting a string like `VPLS-` into a character class, each character seems to be treated as a logical OR eg: `V or P or L or S or -`, which means anything containing a `V` as the first character will be matched and excluded.

Weirdly though this isn't entirely consistent - re-arranging the letters in `VPLS` gives different results eg: `PVLS-` doesn't match, but `SLPV-` does - I don't understand why:

```
groups {
    RI-DESCRIPTION {
        routing-instances {
            "<[!VPLS-*]*>" {
                description "This is from an apply-group";
            }
        }
    }
}

root# show routing-instances | display inheritance no-comments
DIFFERENT-VR {
    description "This is from an apply-group";
    instance-type virtual-router;
}
PVLS-2 {
    instance-type virtual-router;
}
RV-1 {
    description "This is from an apply-group";
    instance-type virtual-router;
}
SLPV-1 {
    description "This is from an apply-group";
    instance-type virtual-router;
}
VPLS-1 {
    instance-type vpls;
}
VPLS-2 {
    instance-type vpls;
}
VREF-2 {
    instance-type virtual-router;
}
```

One solution might be to use `set routing-instance VPLS-xxx apply-groups-except ALLOW_MARTIAN_192` under each VPLS instance - unfortunately you'd have to do this manually, as you can't use `apply-groups-except` within a `groups` configuration matching on `<VPLS-*>`.

Comment: Can you try this one: `^(!VPLS-|!V)*` ?

Comment: No luck @AndreyProkhorov - I don't think that's a valid regex for groups - it didn't apply that description to any of the routing-instances I have defined above